# Series of books man trying to improve the technology of earth

Tags: story-identification

About 30 years ago my grandfather was reading a series of sci fi books I am trying to identify.

The main premise of the series is that a man either from another planet or the future has come to Earth to try and make it suitable for his own people to live. He wants to improve the atmosphere, increase scientific knowledge etc.

The series ran over several books, at least 5-6 I think.

Answer (score 2):

You do not supply much information (for example, in what epoch does the main action take place?), and yet, for some reason, I keep thinking of [Conrad Stargard, the Cross-Time Engineer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conrad_Stargard).

Even if the only attempt at "improving the atmosphere" is a side reference to Conrad Stargard not wanting to develop the internal combustion engine and oil-based fuels to the levels of the XXth Century because of pollution concerns (this, if memory serves, about midway in *Lord Conrad's Lady*).